# Got logged out of account, don't remember password and don't have the email address or phone number listed

Tags: account-recovery, facebook-account

Can't get into my account can't remember password and don't have email account and phone # on account

Answer (score 0):

Make a new account! You can add your friends again, and you can still save/repost everything public.

Spring cleaning: the unintended version.